# How to get join values in pivot?

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently having the dataset like-

```
    customerID  store_code  mode
    BBID_204100102  2655    a
    BBID_204100102  2906    b
    BBID_204100102  2906    d 
    BBID_204100150  4986    c      
    BBID_204100150  4986    a
    BBID_204100277  4986    d                                                 
    BBID_204100310  4986    d
```

and i want something like

```
    customerID  store_code  a   b  c  d
0   BBID_204100102  2655    1   0   0  0
1   BBID_204100102  2906    0   1   0  0
2   BBID_204100150  4986    1   0   1  0 
3   BBID_204100277  4986    0   0   0  1
4   BBID_204100310  4986    0   0   0  1
```

first of it makes pivot on customer ud and student id and then it will encode mode in above manner.

Comment: I reopen question because necessary `get_dummies` with some preprocessing.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks, I didn't notice the preprocessing involved.

Comment: pivot solution added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and `max` by both levels:

```
df = (pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(['customerID','store_code']), prefix='', prefix_sep='')
        .max(level=[0,1])
        .reset_index())
print (df)
       customerID  store_code  a  b  c  d
0  BBID_204100102        2655  1  0  0  0
1  BBID_204100102        2906  0  1  0  1
2  BBID_204100150        4986  1  0  1  0
3  BBID_204100277        4986  0  0  0  1
4  BBID_204100310        4986  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1** Using `pivot_table`

```
In [3781]: df.pivot_table(index=['customerID','store_code'], columns='mode',
                          aggfunc=len, fill_value=0).reset_index()
Out[3781]:
mode      customerID  store_code  a  b  c  d
0     BBID_204100102        2655  1  0  0  0
1     BBID_204100102        2906  0  1  0  1
2     BBID_204100150        4986  1  0  1  0
3     BBID_204100277        4986  0  0  0  1
4     BBID_204100310        4986  0  0  0  1
```

---

**Option 2** Using `groupby`

```
In [3793]: (df.groupby(['customerID', 'store_code', 'mode']).size()
              .unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index())
Out[3793]:
mode      customerID  store_code  a  b  c  d
0     BBID_204100102        2655  1  0  0  0
1     BBID_204100102        2906  0  1  0  1
2     BBID_204100150        4986  1  0  1  0
3     BBID_204100277        4986  0  0  0  1
4     BBID_204100310        4986  0  0  0  1
```

---

**Option 3** Using `set_index` and `unstack`

```
In [3771]: (df.assign(v=1).set_index(['customerID', 'store_code', 'mode'])['v']
              .unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index())
Out[3771]:
mode      customerID  store_code  a  b  c  d
0     BBID_204100102        2655  1  0  0  0
1     BBID_204100102        2906  0  1  0  1
2     BBID_204100150        4986  1  0  1  0
3     BBID_204100277        4986  0  0  0  1
4     BBID_204100310        4986  0  0  0  1
```